# Binding LineSeries values to object fields

Tags: c#, wpf, wpftoolkit

I'm using the 2010 release of the WPF Toolkit for DataVisualization.

If I want to create a LineSeries chart programmatically, this is what I did before. This code works and plots the data successfully:

```
public class TrendData {
    public string Group;
    public IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<DateTime, decimal>> Series;
}
...
//somewhere within my chart update method
foreach (TrendData line in DataCollection) {
   LineSeries l = new LineSeries() {
      DependentValuePath = "Value",
      IndependentValuePath = "Key",
      Title = line.Group,
      ItemsSource = line.Series
   };
   Chart.Series.Add(l);
}
```

This works without issue. However, I want to stored other values with the data points, because I want to display additional information on mouseover of a DataPoint. So I naively tried this:

```
public class TrendData {
   public string Group;
   public IEnumerable<PointData> Series;
}
public class PointData {
   public DateTime time;
   public decimal rate;
   public int x;
}
...
//somewhere within my chart update method
foreach (TrendData line in DataCollection) {
   LineSeries l = new LineSeries() {
      DependentValuePath = "rate",
      IndependentValuePath = "time",
      Title = line.Group,
      ItemsSource = line.Series
   };
   Chart.Series.Add(l);
}
```

This doesn't work, instead giving me an `InvalidOperationException: "No suitable axis is available for plotting the dependent value."` from DataPointSeries.

Ideas? Am I doing this completely wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Turns out this works absolutely perfectly. I just had a typo in my code elsewhere that was causing this.

Comment: I also got this error because of a typo in my DependentValueBinding.